# scalaxb requires missing type

Tags: xml, scala, xsd, wsdl, scalaxb

I'm trying to use scalaxb to generate a web service from two wsdl files.
Here are the files: https://services.pwsdemo.com/WSDL/PwsDemo_creditcardtransactionservice.xml.
https://services.pwsdemo.com/WSDL/PwsDemo_creditcardmanagementservice.xml
I downloaded it to my local machine and ran the following command:
`$ scalaxb PwsDemo_creditcardmanagementservice.xml PwsDemo_creditcardtransactionservice.xml -p delta`

I got the error:
`Referenced type {http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ThreeDelta.Web.Services.ECLinx.Definitions}ClientCredentials was not found.`

I have a ClientCredentials class in my code, it's really simple:

```
class Halo_3Delta_Request_ClientCredentials
{
    protected $ClientCode;
    protected $UserName;
    protected $Password;

    public function __construct($clientCode, $username, $password)
    {
        $this->ClientCode = $clientCode;
        $this->UserName = $username;
        $this->Password = $password;
    }
}
```

What would be a good way to provide the missing type?

***Update:***
I located this type definition already present in the wsdl files:

```
  <xs:complexType name="ClientCredentials">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ClientCode" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Password" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="UserName" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

So I guess the question now is how to rearrange those files so they pass validation.

Answer (score 0):

The error is merely in XML structure.
Here are the two files rearranged so that they can be parsed by scalaxb:

[PwsDemo_creditcardmanagementservice.xml](https://gist.github.com/vasily802/79054b947867bce7484f127e5d9473e7)

[PwsDemo_creditcardtransactionservice.xml](https://gist.github.com/vasily802/f1ba56913dd6c672ef2492e57251eb4d)